# Incorrect sum of when I join a second table to first table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:

1. **orders** (id,site,orderdate,shipping_fees,amazone_fees,totalAmount,profit_loss,processing_fees)
2. **orderItemDetails** (id,orderId,product_name,product_expense)

[image]

I wrote this query for getting data but I don't get data that I want. So please correct my query so that I get data that are in the image above.

```
SELECT 
    o.totalshippingfees,
    o.totalamazonefees,
    o.totalorderamount,
    o.totalprofitloss,
    o.totalprocessing_fees,
    oi.totalproductexpense,
    o.site
FROM (
    SELECT 
        orderdate,
        site,
        sum(orders.shipping_fees) as totalshippingfees,
        sum(orders.amazone_fees) as totalamazonefees,
        sum(orders.totalAmount) as totalorderamount,
        sum(orders.profit_loss) as totalprofitloss,
        sum(orders.processing_fees) as totalprocessing_fees
    FROM orders
    group by site
) as o
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        site,
        sum(orderItemDetails.product_expense) as totalproductexpense,
        sum(orders.shipping_fees) as totalshippingfees,
        sum(orders.amazone_fees) as totalamazonefees,
        sum(orders.totalAmount) as totalorderamount,
        sum(orders.profit_loss) as totalprofitloss,
        sum(orders.processing_fees) as totalprocessing_fees
    from orders 
    LEFT JOIN orderItemDetails ON orders.id = orderItemDetails.orderId 
    group by site
) as oi
WHERE MONTH(o.orderdate) = '".$monthNo."' AND YEAR(o.orderdate)= '".$monthyear[1]."'
```

Comment: Where is your join condition?

Comment: Can you share a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ link?

Comment: @vivek_23 db-fiddle link : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tYp4c3F1Qa4ZYXkrKmPFqs/0

Comment: @BhoomiPatel You will have to create table and insert rows on the left column and your actual query on the right column and then save and share the link. I am asking this because we can test and give a proper answer.

Comment: @vivek_23 see i updated db-fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tYp4c3F1Qa4ZYXkrKmPFqs/1

Comment: @BhoomiPatel This looks fine. What is the objective of the query? What kind of data do you want to retrieve?

Comment: @vivek_23 plz see image for what kind of data i want.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel Yes I can see the image but I want to know the purpose of the query, like you want to select all fees data of a particular month and year grouped by ... ?

Comment: @vivek_23 just i want totalshippingfees,totalamazonefees,totalorderamount,totalprofitloss,totalprocessing_fees,site from orders table and totalproductexpense from orderItemDetails.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you are looking for in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a simple group by `site` on `orders` and group by `site` on `orderItemDetails` and join them on `site`.

```
select *
from (
    select 
      sum(shipping_fees) as totalshippingfees,
      sum(amazone_fees) as totalamazonefees,
      sum(totalAmount) as totalorderamount,
      sum(profit_loss) as totalprofitloss,
      sum(processing_fees) as totalprocessing_fees,
      site
    from orders 
    group by site
 ) d1
 join (
        select
            sum(product_expense) as totalproductexpense,
            site
        from orders o
        left join orderItemDetails od
        on o.id = od.orderId 
        group by site
      ) d2
on d1.site = d2.site
```

**DB Fiddle:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dkpctq1XrzB7bfsrojaZHd/2

**Update:**

You can add a `where` condition for date filtering as below:

```
select *
from (
    select 
      sum(shipping_fees) as totalshippingfees,
      sum(amazone_fees) as totalamazonefees,
      sum(totalAmount) as totalorderamount,
      sum(profit_loss) as totalprofitloss,
      sum(processing_fees) as totalprocessing_fees,
      site
    from orders 
    where MONTH(orderdate) = 10 AND YEAR(orderdate) = 2019
    group by site
 ) d1
 join (
        select
            sum(product_expense) as totalproductexpense,
            site
        from orders o
        left join orderItemDetails od
        on o.id = od.orderId 
        where MONTH(o.orderdate) = 10 AND YEAR(o.orderdate) = 2019
        group by o.site
      ) d2
    on d1.site = d2.site
```

**DB Fiddle:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgZbS5U1oSgPAGX34URD22/0

Comment: @BhoomiPatel Yours has more rows though. I am sure I have missed something.

Comment: this query not giving me excetly what i want.

Comment: this query not giving me right value of totalshippingfees, totalamazonefees, totalorderamount, totalprofitloss, totalprocessing_fees. only totalproductexpense value right.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel Are the results grouped by order id or orderitemdetails ID as well?

Comment: results grouped by site.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel You have only 2 `site` values as of now, i.e, `1` and `4`. If it's grouped by site in the final results, you can't have multiple `1`'s in your final result.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel What is the exact purpose of the query? What kind of data are we supposed to get here?

Comment: see my above image. only 1 & 2 i want and in productexpense i want 100 in 2 row insted of 560. and 3 & 4  i don't want.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel I think I get it now. I will let you know soon.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel Glad to help. You can add the where condition of date in the first select subquery if you like.

Comment: i added where condition and getting the correct data. thank you. :)

Comment: @BhoomiPatel Apparently it had some logical errors, so I had to reject the edit. Anyway, I have updated my answer with date condition as well :)